# In Microsoft Bot Framework which Activity can be Triggered if Teams Manifest File is Changed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a Microsoft Bot Framework App, which is published to Microsoft Teams using Teams Admin Center.

In my earlier code, I use to add/save conversation reference, inside `OnMessageActivityAsync` method. But there might be instance where the User may not have yet interacted with the Bot and hence no conversation reference is recorded to enable Push Notification.

So I have changed my code to add/update conversation reference inside `OnMembersAddedAsync` method for any new members for which Bot will be installed via Teams Admin Center.

Also I would be changing version value inside Teams Manifest Schema and Update it via **Manage Apps** in Teams Admin Center.

My question is, any Activity Handler / Event methods will be invoked after changing Manifest file and re-publishing the App?

If no Activities would be triggered, than what could be an alternative way to insert user conversation reference in order to enable Push Notification without Re-Installation of the App, for the previously added users.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no method that gets invoked when user updates an app. However in TeamsActivityHandler we have method that gets invoked when User add or remove an app-> [*onInstallationUpdate(BotHandler)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#onInstallationUpdate_BotHandler_).

Refer this [*link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.teams.teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) to see all method inside TeamsActivityHandler.

I didn't come up with any workaround that will send notification to user when App got updated.